# crear 5 elementos dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

En realidad ya puedo crear los 5 elementos dinamicamente y borrarlos, pero mi problema es al momento de generarlos les pongo un id que es div1, div2, div3, div4 y div5, cuando creo los 5 elementos y por ejemplo borro el div3 y vuelvo a crear uno me quede así div1, div2, div4, div4 y div5, utilizo una variable num++ y al borrar uso un num--, como podría hacer que cuando borre por ejemplo el div2 y el div3, al momento de crear me vuelva a poner esos id's por ejemplo div1, div4, div5, div2 y div3.

```js
num = 0;

function crear(obj) {

  if (num < 5) {
    num++;
    fi = document.getElementById('primerCurso'); // 1
    contenedor = document.createElement('div'); // 2
    contenedor.id = 'div' + num;
    contenedor.classList = 'col-md-12 form-inline'; // 3
    contenedor.style = 'margin-bottom:10px;';
    fi.insertBefore(contenedor, obj); // 4


    h2 = document.createElement('H2');
    h2.classList = 'personalizado';
    textoh2 = document.createTextNode('Curso con certificación');
    h2.appendChild(textoh2);
    contenedor.appendChild(h2);

    inputArchivo = document.createElement('input'); // 5
    inputArchivo.type = 'file'; // 6
    inputArchivo.name = 'curso_C' + num; // 6
    inputArchivo.id = 'curso_C' + num;
    inputArchivo.classList = 'form-control';
    inputArchivo.setAttribute('onChange', 'return validarCursoC' + num + '()');
    contenedor.appendChild(inputArchivo); // 7

    parrafo = document.createElement('P');
    parrafo.id = 'imagenCursoC' + num;
    contenedor.appendChild(parrafo);

    contenedor2 = document.createElement('DIV');
    contenedor2.classList = 'col-md-6 form-inline';
    contenedor.appendChild(contenedor2);

    label = document.createElement('LABEL');
    textoLabel = document.createTextNode('Fecha de incio del curso');
    label.appendChild(textoLabel);
    contenedor2.appendChild(label);

    inputDateInicio = document.createElement('INPUT');
    inputDateInicio.type = 'date';
    inputDateInicio.name = 'inicio_curso' + num;
    inputDateInicio.min = '1900-01-01';
    inputDateInicio.max = '<?php $hoy = date('
    Y - m - j '); echo $hoy; ?>';
    inputDateInicio.classList = 'form-control';
    inputDateInicio.id = 'inicio_curso' + num;
    inputDateInicio.style = 'width:11em;';
    contenedor2.appendChild(inputDateInicio);

    contenedor3 = document.createElement('DIV');
    contenedor3.classList = 'col-md-6 form-inline';
    contenedor.appendChild(contenedor3);

    label2 = document.createElement('LABEL');
    textoLabel2 = document.createTextNode('Fecha de incio del curso');
    label2.appendChild(textoLabel2);
    contenedor3.appendChild(label2);

    inputDateFin = document.createElement('INPUT');
    inputDateFin.type = 'date';
    inputDateFin.name = 'termino_curso' + num;
    inputDateFin.min = '1900-01-01';
    inputDateFin.max = '<?php $hoy = date('
    Y - m - j '); echo $hoy; ?>';
    inputDateFin.classList = 'form-control';
    inputDateFin.id = 'termino_curso' + num;
    inputDateFin.style = 'width:11em;';
    contenedor3.appendChild(inputDateFin);

    contenedor4 = document.createElement('DIV');
    contenedor4.classList = 'col-md-12 form-inline';
    contenedor.appendChild(contenedor4);

    label3 = document.createElement('LABEL');
    textoLabel3 = document.createTextNode('Breve descripcion del curso:');
    label3.appendChild(textoLabel3);
    contenedor4.appendChild(label3);

    textArea = document.createElement('TEXTAREA');
    textArea.classList = 'form-control';
    textArea.name = 'comentario' + 1;
    textArea.id = 'comment1';
    textArea.maxlength = 300;
    textArea.rows = 5;
    contenedor4.appendChild(textArea);

    ele = document.createElement('input'); // 5
    ele.type = 'button'; // 6
    ele.value = 'Borrar'; // 8
    ele.name = 'div' + num; // 8
    ele.onclick = function() {
      borrar(this.name)
    } // 9
    contenedor.appendChild(ele); // 7
  } else {

    alert('Solo puedes agregar 5 cursos, si deseas agregar más, en la pagina de "Editar empleado" lo puedes hacer.');
  }
}

function borrar(obj) {
  num--;
  fi = document.getElementById('primerCurso'); // 1 
  fi.removeChild(document.getElementById(obj)); // 10
}
```

el HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Crear input file</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>

<body>
 

 
 
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset id="primerCurso">
<input type="button" value="Crear" onclick="crear(this)">
</fieldset>


</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: la mas facil de hacer es asegurarte que solo puedas eliminar el ultimo, de otro modo, tendras que poner una calse a los `div`, con las cual puedas recorrerlo y re asignarles los nuevo valores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cree un pequeño código para que te guies. El primer paso que hice fue crea una función donde se creaban los **divs** dinamicamente(crearDiv()), luego allí adentro de esa función llamo a la función que valida el **id** que puede usar, esa función se llama **idDiv()**. Dentro de la función **idDiv()** simplemente coloro un **for** donde evalúo si ese **id** esta en uso o no, si **NO** esta en uso lo retorno, es muy simple, también te hice un botón donde puedes eliminar los div y probar como se van creando y tomando el **id** que le corresponde como tu quieres, espero te sirva:

```js
const crearDiv = () => {

  const numDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("item").length;
  
  if(numDivs < 5){
  
    const contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor-divs");
    let id = idDiv();
    let nuevoDiv = `<div id="`+id+`" class="item">
                      Este es el DIV con el id <strong>`+id +`</strong> <input type="button" class="eliminar" onClick="eliminarDiv(this)" value="Eliminar este DIV">
                    </div>`;
    
    contenedor.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", nuevoDiv);
    
  }else{
    alert('Solo puedes agregar 5 cursos, si deseas agregar más, en la pagina de "Editar empleado" lo puedes hacer.');
  }

}

const idDiv = () => {
  
  for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    if(document.getElementById("div"+i) === null){
      return "div"+i;
    }
  }

}

const eliminarDiv = (obj) => {
  const div = obj.parentElement;
  div.remove();
}
```

```css
#contenedor-divs{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-top:10px;
  width:100%;
}

#contenedor-divs .item{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <fieldset id="primerCurso">
  <input type="button" value="Crear Nuevo Div" onclick="crearDiv()">
  <div id="contenedor-divs"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias David, de lujo el código que me pasaste, hace lo que requiero, voy a modificarlo con lo que requiero, cualquier cosa mando un nuevo comentario, nuevamente muchas gracias, tienes un lugar en el Cielo!! :)

Comment: Hola de nuevo David, ya hice las modificaciones, al parecer ya funciona bien, solo una duda, me marcaba error al querer eliminar el div cuando lo tenía en un documento .js, lo que hice fue pasar el código a mi archivo php en etiquetas <script>'codigo'</script> y ya me funciono, cuál sería la causa? de ante mano gracia sy que tengas un excelente día.

Comment: Que error te arrojaba?

Comment: el error es este 'eliminarDiv(this) is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick' , gracias.

Comment: el error es que el elemento que es creado por alguna razón no esta encontrando la función, lo motivos pueden ser N, tendría que ver todo tu código.

Comment: Si, y le moví a todo para ver si chocaba con algo pero no encontré nada, por el momento lo dejare en mi código PHP, ya me funciona bien, Gracias por responder! :)